# HTA Browse to file

Tags: vbscript, hta

Im trying to browse to files.

It works fine as a simple vbs but when inside a HTA produces an Error.

Like this:

```
sUserList = BrowseToFile
msgbox sUserList

Function BrowseToFile
    Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"").GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
    BrowseToFile = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
End Function
```

ERROR:

```
Line 130: Is the wShell.exec
Char 203:
Unterminated String Constant.
```

I could call a separate vbs and write to file then get it that way.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objTest" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest"
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Path = BrowseToFile
msgbox "Path = " & Path




Function BrowseToFile
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
BrowseToFile = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
End Function

</SCRIPT>

<body>



</body>

Comment: _Please_ do not post code snippets in comments as it becomes slightly unreadable. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28217005/edit) instead, _please_.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong escaped nested double quotes: instead of

```
... new ActiveXObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")...
```

use single quotation marks as follows:

```
... new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')...
```

**Edit**: in your `HTATest.hta` I see some weird for me approach:

- nested `<script> ... <script> ... </script> ... </script>`
- launched `mshta.exe` from `HTATest.hta` i.e., as a matter of fact, from `mshta.exe HTATest.hta`

Next `hta` *works*(?):

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>HTA Test
    </title> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="objTest" APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" > 
  </head> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Path = BrowseToFile
msgboxx= "Path = " & Path
Function BrowseToFile()
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  mshtapar="about:<input type=file id=FILE>"_
   & "<script>FILE.click();"_
   & "new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);"_
   & "close();"_
   & "resizeTo(0,0);"_
   & "<//script>"
  msgboxy= "param =" & mshtapar
  Set oExec=wShell.Exec( "mshta.exe " & """" & mshtapar & """")
End Function
</SCRIPT>
  <body>
  </body>
```

Note `<//script>` instead of `</script>` within `BrowseToFile()` function. However, this workaround I don't regard as a solution...

---

Here's a simple `hta` example: does the same as yours one but without troubles

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>HTA Test
    </title> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="objTest" APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" > 
  </head> 

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
<!--
-->
</SCRIPT>

  <body>
    <input type="file" id=FILE>
  </body>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objTest" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTATest"
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Path = BrowseToFile
msgbox "Path = " & Path




Function BrowseToFile
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
BrowseToFile = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
End Function

</SCRIPT>

<body>



</body>

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for that. Much appreciated. I'll work it in and see how it goes.